# Why use clone keyword here

Tags: php, spl

I am watching a tutorial of SPL and here is the code that confuses me

```
<?php

$directory = new DirectoryIterator('common/images');

foreach ($directory as $file)
{
    if($file->isFile())
        $files[] = clone $file;
}

echo $files[1]->getFileName();
```

If i don't use `clone` keyword in the foreach loop, I am not able to see the filename. Why is that so when i am pushing the whole object inside the `$files` array.

Thanks

Updated Part

While the above code i have to used the `clone` keyword. Based on the answer below that we are using `clone` to create a copy of object not reference. That doesn't seems to be a valid reason in this case. Consider the following example which does not need clone keyword and is working as expected

```
<?php

$filesystem = new FilesystemIterator('common/images');
foreach ($filesystem as $file)
{
    $files[] = $file;
}

echo $files[0]->getFileName();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since php5, operator `=` creates reference to object, so without `clone` you will put pointer/reference to variable `$file` into array.

But this variable is used only within loop and will/could be destroyed after `foreach`, because it out of the scope.

This is why you need to create copy of it to put into array and have access to it after loop.

UPDATE: Actually the difference a little bit deeper in this case, check out [this article](http://paulyg.github.io/blog/2014/06/03/directoryiterator-vs-filesystemiterator.html). `DirectoryIterator` returns the same object, this is why you have to clone (with its current) state during iteration, but `FilesystemIterator` returns new object, which can be put into array without clone.

Comment: Although i understand your logic. But as i was putting whole $file variable in $files. Isn't it like we do not need copy or reference here but actually a new variable that contains the $file object.

Comment: can you please look at the updated part ? I unaccepted your answer after going through that updated example.

Answer (score 0):

actually you can do it without `clone` while your logic is inside the foreach loop :

```
<?php
  $dir = new DirectoryIterator(dirname(__FILE__));
  foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
    echo $fileinfo->getFilename() . "\n";
  }
?>
```

[sample from php.net manual](http://php.net/manual/fr/directoryiterator.getfilename.php#example-4303)

Comment: I know, The problem was putting it into array.